# How do I get the url of the current include script in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a file called `index.php` which includes a class from another file (`class/event.class.php`) with the following code:

```
 <?php
      require_once('class/event.class.php');
      $evt = new Event;
      $evt->doSomething();
 ?>
```

The file `event.class.php` should be able to read the URL used in the request (**not** `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME")` to the file.

ie: `http://localhost:8888/class/event.class.php`

How do I do that?

Comment: no its not making sense, post the code which is not working

Comment: Hey dude we cannot access your localhost.. Please edit your answer and add proper details.

Comment: @mkram0 I want the class Event withing the file event.class.php to get the url to that file. I know you can't access my localhost, but that's the url I want PHP to generate

Comment: Right so you want to get a url to that event.class.php file true? In that case, get the current URL into one variable and append the filename to it.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `$_SERVER` array, example:

```
$protocol = 'http';
$port = '';

if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) && strcasecmp( $_SERVER['HTTPS'], 'on' ) == 0 ) {
    $protocol = 'https';
}
if ( isset( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) ) {
    $port = ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
}

// Don't display the standard ports :80 for http and :443 for https
if ( ( $protocol == 'http' && $port == ':80' ) || ( $protocol == 'https' && $port == ':443' ) ) {
    $port = '';
}

$host_url = $protocol . '://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $port;
$base_url = rtrim( str_replace( basename( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ), '/' );
```

Comment: Lots of errors:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\wamp\wwwT2\class\timeline.class.php on line 53

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\wamp\wwwT2\class\timeline.class.php on line 54

Warning: basename() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given in C:\wamp\wwwT2\class\timeline.class.php on line 54

Warning: str_replace() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given in C:\wamp\wwwT2\class\timeline.class.php on line 54

Comment: Sorry, copy-pasted it from a system so had to modify it a little bit. I'll took the syntax errors out manually - try again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice succinct line I have used for a long time, and it works very nicely.

```
$myURL = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') ? 'https' : 'http').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

echo $myURL;
```

**EDIT** Using an edited version of this function I [lifted from the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php#97885), and the `__FILE__` magic constant, it can be done like this (untested):

```
function getRelativePath ( $path, $compareTo ) {

    // Replace \ with / and remove leading/trailing slashes (for Windows)
    $path = trim(str_replace('\\','/',$path),'/');
    $compareTo = trim(str_replace('\\','/',$compareTo),'/');

    // simple case: $compareTo is in $path
    if (strpos($path, $compareTo) === 0) {
        $offset = strlen($compareTo) + 1;
        return substr($path, $offset);
    }

    $relative  = array();
    $pathParts = explode('/', $path);
    $compareToParts = explode('/', $compareTo);

    foreach($compareToParts as $index => $part) {
        if (isset($pathParts[$index]) && $pathParts[$index] == $part) {
            continue;
        }
        $relative[] = '..';
    }

    foreach( $pathParts as $index => $part ) {
        if (isset($compareToParts[$index]) && $compareToParts[$index] == $part) {
            continue;
        }
        $relative[] = $part;
    }

    return implode('/',$relative);

}

$myURL = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') ? 'https' : 'http').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.ltrim(getRelativePath(realpath($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),__FILE__),'/');

echo $myURL;
```

Comment: That shows the location of the index.php file. I need the url to the events.class.php file, so this doesn't really help me because I can't assume that events.class.php is inside the folder "class"

Comment: He has to get the URL of the file. And URL's do not include '..', or do they?

Comment: @mkram0 They can, and servers should handle this correctly, but you are correct in that they probably shouldn't. Given the above, they won't unless the included file is *above* `index.php` in the directory structure, but they potentially could do. You could pass the resulting path through the `getRelativePath()` function again, and compare it to the full path of document root, although this of course does not take into account aliases, rewrites and the fact that the included file may not be under document root at all. So it's not perfect, but it's about as good as you will get...

Answer (score 1):

What I do to get a browser path to my files (I include this in index.php, but having this code in event.class.php would return the folder):

```
$this_file = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/';

$a_file_that_you_want_to_access_by_url = $this_file.'class/event.class.php';
```

Also, if you want to access the current directory 'root' in all of your .php files define a constant like this:

```
define('uri_root',          dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/',  true);
$a_file_that_you_want_to_access_by_url = uri_root.'class/event.class.php';
```

This script will echo the script name with all sub-folders

```
echo dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```